# Generating functions for election results

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

This is from my textbook which does not give solutions to problems (i.e. not homework).

> Find the generating series for the number of election results involving 4 candidates with respect to the number of voters.

This is easy and is obviously $(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^4$. However, the next question is hard:

> Do the same, except assume that all 4 candidates vote for themselves.

How would I solve this problem then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first question, each of the four candidates can have $0$ or more people who vote for them. In the second question, each candidate is guaranteed at least $1$ vote (themselves). Hence, we obtain:
$$
(x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots)^4
$$